# Appending frame to start of mov sequence with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to append a frame from a png file to an existing mov movie.

I have some existing commands passed on to me and I'm trying to work out why they aren't working.

The first command seems to do the correct thing it converts the still ("slate") frame png into a mov.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i X:/slate.png -r 24000/1001 -frames:v 1 -vf scale=1920x1080:flags=lanczos:out_color_matrix=bt709,pad=1920:1080:0:0:black,setsar=1,fps=24000/1001 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -y X:/slate.mov*
```

The second command should concatenate the still frame to the front of the mov sequence.

So you see one frame of the still frame, and then the rest of the sequence plays.

```
ffmpeg -y -i X:/slate.mov -i X:/sequence.mov -filter_complex [0:v] [1:v] concat=n=2:v=1:a=0 [v] -map [v] X:/delivery.mov*
```

The problem is the second command actually makes a 100KB file with one frame. It doesn't actually concatenate the two together. The sequence part isn't included in the resulting mov.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Actually the concatenated sequence is being written out as a 100KB file, with all the frames. As confirmed by opening the video with vlc.

So my question is why does the output file size drop so much, the "sequence.mov" that is being concatenated is more than 60MB.

I'm very confused because the quality is decent when viewing the output file in vlc. How could this be, if the file was only 100KB? 

Is the file produced somehow confusing Windows with its size?